# Correct lifetime for Into<Foo> with reference as a parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm not sure what the appropriate question to ask here, but I have an issue with getting the correct lifetime set in a generic method. The full code is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3b4d76708605dfbdedaa943528678c51&version=stable&backtrace=0), but the basic issue is that I have a method looking something like below, but I get a lifetime error. Nothing from the `&params` reference will be embedded into the struct that's returned from `.into()`, so this should be safe. What do I need to get this to work?

```rust
pub fn index<'a, T, R, P>(repository: T, query: &'a str) -> Result<Vec<<R as ToJson>::Attrs>, QueryStringParseError>
    where
        T: JsonApiRepository<'a, T = R>,
        P: 'a,
        R: ToJson,
        R: QueryString<'a, Params = P>,
        <R as ToJson>::Attrs: From<(R, &'a P)>,
        QueryStringParseError: From<<T as JsonApiRepository<'a>>::Error>
{
    let params = <R as QueryString>::from_str(query)?;
    let list = repository.find_all(&params)?;

    // What's the correct lifetime incantation for this to work?
    // No references will be embedded in `R::Attrs`, so this
    // should be safe
    let data: Vec<<R as ToJson>::Attrs> = list.into_iter().map(|e| (e, &params).into()).collect();
    Ok(data)
}
```

(amended question with error below)

```
rustc 1.16.0 (30cf806ef 2017-03-10)
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `params`, which is owned by the current function
  --> <anon>:16:64
   |
16 |     let data: Vec<<R as ToJson>::Attrs> = list.into_iter().map(|e| (e, &params).into()).collect();
   |                                                                ^^^      ------ `params` is borrowed here
   |                                                                |
   |                                                                may outlive borrowed value `params`
   |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `params` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
   |     let data: Vec<<R as ToJson>::Attrs> = list.into_iter().map(move |e| (e, &params).into()).collect();
```

Comment: I'd *strongly* encourage to to review what a [MCVE] is and work on the *minimal* aspect. Something that specifies **12** where clauses is... very unusual, to say the least. Additionally, why have you decided to not paste the error message you get?

Comment: Also *"**Nothing** from the &params reference will **not be** embedded"*, vs. *"**There no references** will be embedded in `R::Attrs`"*

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity. I had already tried to strip it down, and I was trying to reduce the test case further, but I now see that you have answered my question. Thanks (and sorry yet again for my crappy question)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get (which I don't know why you didn't share):

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `params`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:22:64
   |
22 |     let data: Vec<<R as ToJson>::Attrs> = list.into_iter().map(|e| (e, &params).into()).collect();
   |                                                                ^^^      ------ `params` is borrowed here
   |                                                                |
   |                                                                may outlive borrowed value `params`
   |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `params` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
   |     let data: Vec<<R as ToJson>::Attrs> = list.into_iter().map(move |e| (e, &params).into()).collect();
```

You create `params` inside your function, but then all of the trait bounds require that the lifetime of `params` must match the lifetime of the string passed in from outside. It's not possible to satisfy that bound, and it looks like the reference to `params` has to live longer than the function, via the closure. Thus the so-so error message.

You should not tie these lifetimes together. Use [*higher-ranked trait bounds*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) instead:

```
pub fn index<T, R, P, S, F>
    (repository: T,
     query: &str)
     -> Result<JsonApiArray<<R as ToJson>::Attrs>, QueryStringParseError>
    where T: JsonApiRepository<T = R>,
          P: Params,
          P: Default,
          P: TypedParams<SortField = S, FilterField = F>,
          P: for<'b> TryFrom<(&'b str, SortOrder, P), Err = QueryStringParseError>,
          P: for<'b> TryFrom<(&'b str, Vec<&'b str>, P), Err = QueryStringParseError>,
          R: ToJson,
          R: for<'b> QueryString<'b, Params = P, SortField = S, FilterField = F>,
          R: JsonApiResource<Params = P>,
          <R as ToJson>::Attrs: for<'b> From<(R, &'b P)>,
          QueryStringParseError: From<<T as JsonApiRepository>::Error>
{
```

Comment: Thanks yet again, I see that I'll have to do some reading about higher ranked trait bounds now!